# GMX and Mail.com Compose URL

Tags: webmail

Are GMX and Mail.com webmail clients the same company? I was wondering I made an addon that allows users to open `mailto:blah@blah.com` links in a new tab with the `To:` line populated with the `blah@blah.com` so I was looking for that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GMX aquired mail.com in 2010. Look at this [press release](http://www.mail.com/press/538716-gmx-acquires-mailcom.html) for further informations.

Comment: Thank you so much! By any chance do you the URL that redirects you to compose mail message with "To:" line filled out?

Comment: Hey @Noitidart, have you found the URL for GMX?